# How to bind overloaded functions with Luabind?

Tags: c++, scripting, lua, luabind

I am writing a game engine in c++ which will provide Lua scripting ( for which wrapping I am using Luabind ) and I am having some problems to bind overloaded functions. Namely: I have am overloaded function :

`void setGlobalPosition(const Vec3& position);`

`void setGlobalPosition(Real x, Real y, Real z);`

And I would like to expose both of these to lua.
obviously this is wrong:

`luabind::module(L)[
        luabind::class_<Critter::Body>("Body")
            .def("setGlobalPosition", &Critter::Body::setGlobalPosition )
    ];`

I have found a way to do it on this site http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/luabindLuaAndOgre3d.aspx?msg=3376320 (very good tutorial for Luabind - I strongly recommend it) like this :

`luabind::module(L)[
        luabind::class_<Critter::Body>("Body")
            .def("setGlobalPosition", (void( Critter::Body::*)(const Vector3&))Critter::Body::setGlobalPosition )
    ];`

but it also gives me errors (I can attach them if somebody is interested).

I have also tried 
`.def("setGlobalPosition", Critter::Body::setGlobalPosition<Vector3> )`
but still errors.

Any ideas how can I do it ?

---

EDIT:
Ok, I have found a way to do it like that:

```
.def("setGlobalPosition", ( void(Critter::Body::*)(Vector3) ) &Critter::Body::setGlobalPosition )
```

from the luabind documentation but I get errors (the first one):

> error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot
>   convert from 'overloaded-function' to
>   'void (__thiscall Critter::Body::*
>   )(Ogre::Vector3)'

but anyway the problem arises cuz this function is inherited (it comes from `NxOgre::Actor::` so I don't that the right approach anyway

---

EDIT 2 :

I have just tried to bind the version of function with 3 floats as parameters and ... surprisingly everything compiles just fine but the version with vector3 does not.... :(

this is what I have used to implement 3 float function:

```
.def("setGlobalPosition", ( void(Critter::Body::*)(float,float,float) ) &Critter::Body::setGlobalPosition )
```

I am stumped about this ;(

Comment: Yes, please do attach the errors. I think you just forgot the `&`.

Comment: Just in case somebody did not see it : I have attached errors and an another way to do this - I think a proper one, but still I get some errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DeadMG pointed out, you are missing an ampersand before the member function.  The tutorial you linked is also missing it.  Some compilers might not care, but g++ does and probably some others do too.

Comment: I did put the `&` but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems quite old now, but I figured since you still don't have the answer to your latest edits:

```
(( void(Critter::Body::*)(Vector3) ) &Critter::Body::setGlobalPosition)
```

is missing the const qualifier and reference-ampersand in the function-type to cast to. It's got to be:

```
(( void(Critter::Body::*)(const Vector3&) ) &Critter::Body::setGlobalPosition)
```

Comment: I have almost forgotten about this question to be honest :) I will try to use your code later on and I will post some results ;)